# Instantiating an custom object and insert

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

I'm having problems with my apex code inserting. I don't know whats going on

here is my code:

// object instance with memory allocation.

```
Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
insert wo;
```

and I have looked at the system.debug log and this is what I'm getting in the log:

23:54:38.198 (198681448)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|===> insert  ===>   Work_Order__c:`{Instructions__c=this is a test, Est_Hours__c=89, Id=a0j1a000000cbuFAAQ}`

but how come its not inserting a new row in the `Work_Order__C` object?

Comment: Why are you saying it's not inserted? it has an Id, which you get only after inserting the record. It seems inserted.

Comment: That code won't run.  The second and third lines don't terminate with a semi colon.  Are you sure this is the right code? What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: yes its look like but i do not see the record in work_oder__c object thats the confusing part

Comment: @Nick: i'm not getting any error, it was typo instead of `comma` I have `simicolon`

Comment: What happens if you pop that Id in the URL?

Comment: @NickCook: its very strange and if I pop that id in the url then I able to see the record otherwise I do not see in the `Recent Work Orders` list as new record

Comment: What filter is on the list view?

Comment: i see the problem that in the list view its has filter on it, can you post that as answer and i will accept that and last, how do i add a picklist value in the insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your discussion with Nick, the view from where you are seeing the records has a filter enabled on it. It may be showing recently opened records 
 You can see all records by creating a new view ( if not already present ) which will not have any filter and shows all records.

Regarding your question about inserting Picklist values,  here is a sample code 
Project__c prj = new Project__c(); 
prj.Project_Name__c='Proj 003'; 
prj.Project_Status__c = 'Active'; 
insert prj;

Here Status field is a picklist value. It is ultimately a string field and a string value is saved.

Hope it is clear, you can try and get back in case of any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use schema as a prefix, sometimes we need to use that. Try this let me know if you're having any more problems.

```
Schema.Work_Order__c wo = new Schema.Work_Order__c();
wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
insert wo;
```